# Counting if (COUNTIF) and add to a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, countif

I have a dataframe which has a lot of duplicates. I found a lot of solutions to find the number of duplicates, but not the way I wanted to. Is there a way to count the duplicates in a new column if it has less than or equal to 2 duplicates?

The dataframe looks like this:

```
    NAME
0  Peter
1  Peter
2  Peter
3   Jack
4   Jack
5   Luke
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
    NAME  Count
0  Peter      0
1  Peter      0
2  Peter      0
3   Jack      1
4   Jack      1
5   Luke      1
```

And then filter it (remove rows) such that I only have a dataframe where `Count` is `1`.

```
    NAME  Count
0   Jack      1
1   Jack      1
2   Luke      1
```

If there is a simpler way to remove duplicates then I am happy to hear about it.

Comment: Do you only want a unique data?

Comment: No. If `Jack` had two data points, then I would also show `1` for that. I'll update the OP with the example.

Comment: Sure, it would be helpful with a sample output

Comment: Now I have updated it. Does it make simpler now? Thanks for replying btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `size` for count to new column and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('NAME')['NAME'].transform('size')
df = df[df['count'] <= 2]

print (df)
   NAME  count
3  Jack      2
4  Jack      2
5  Luke      1
```

If need indicator column convert boolean masn to integer for `True,False` to `1,0` mapping:

```
df['count'] = (df.groupby('NAME')['NAME'].transform('size') <= 2).astype(int)
df = df[df['count'] != 0]

print (df)
   NAME  count
3  Jack      1
4  Jack      1
5  Luke      1
```

Alternative solution with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df['count'] = (df['NAME'].map(df['NAME'].value_counts()) <= 2).astype(int)
df = df[df['count'] != 0]
```

Comment: I envy you for being the fastest!

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = '''\
Name
Peter
Peter
Peter
Jack
Luke'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep=',')     # Recreating dataframe
print(any(df['Name'].duplicated()))                     # Prints True
df['Count'] = (df.groupby('Name')['Name'].transform('size') <= 2).astype(int)

print(df)

# To print only the ones without `0`

df = df[df['Count'] != 0]
print(df)
```

OUTPUT:

```
True                    
    Name  Count
0  Peter      0
1  Peter      0
2  Peter      0
3   Jack      1
4   Luke      1
   Name  Count
3  Jack      1
4  Luke      1
```

Comment: thanks for the effort, but the other suggestion was a simpler code. But worked nevertheless.